# problem with eval() - localhost vs. webserver

Tags: javascript, eval

```
function handleReceive() {
    if (receiveReq.readyState == 4) {
    var chat_div = document.getElementById('div_chat'); 
    var response = eval("(" + receiveReq.responseText + ")");
 .....
    }
}
```

on localhost server the line `var response = eval("(" + receiveReq.responseText + ")");` works fine
, but on server (for example 000webhosting.com) the code brokes here.
I try to check with `alert().` On local server `alert(response);` returns: `[object Object]`,
but on webserver I got nothing, the script stops with executing here.
I try to return chat_div and it's ok. But `var response` don't work, just as any other line after.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Use the browser's developer tools to check for cross site request errors and also to monitor the ajax requests to the server, and their response.

Comment: What happens if you `alert(receiveReq.responseText)` before the `var response` line?

Comment: First problem, you're using eval().

Comment: before var response its ok it return array-Object that I need. Its def about eval, but how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it works on localhost, but fails on a webserver, check if request-URL is not hard-coded to localhost absolute path.

If request URL is correct, just check what is in `receiveReq.responseText` in both cases. If you are using PHP for your server scripts, the problem may be that your code generates warnings or notices and the webserver is configured to display them while your localhost is not.

But you are also right saying that problem is about `eval()`, because as @AlienWebguy stated, the problem is the very fact of using it here. I'm sure there's a better solution.